# How to rewrite the destination path with rsync?

Tags: rsync

Hi I want to use rsync to move data from `sourcehost` to `desthost` but the directory structure is not 100% what I want.

`sourcehost`:

- crappy_dir

  - another_crappy_dir

    - i_like_this_one

      - and_this too

        - file

`desthost` should have:

- my_cool_dir

  - i_like_this_one

    - and_this too

      - file

this is my `files_to_include.txt`:

```
/crappy_dir/another_crappy_dir/i_like_this_one/and_this_too/file
```

and my current test rsync command:

```
desthost# rsync -aAHXv -e ssh --files-from=files_to_include.txt sourcehost:  /my_cool_dir
```

but it creates

```
/my_cool_dir/crappy_dir/another_crappy_dir/i_like_this_one/and_this_too/file
```

**is there any option in rsync to re-write the destination path as I want to?** let's say some magical perl-like-regexp like `--magical-dest-transformation "s@/crappy_dir/another_crappy_dir/@/@"`  will do it. I couldn't come up with a good `--rsync-command` option either. suggestions are welcomed.

Note: this is a several terabytes multi host copy that will take some days to do, a "simple mv" after copying is not good enough because I'll re-run rsync several times. I need it to be smart enough to "peer up" the files.

Comment: What if you change /my_cool_dir to /my_cool_dir/ (note the trailing slash). Nevermind, that won't get want you want either

Comment: `rsync <options> /crappy_dir/another_crappy_dir/i_like_this_one/. desthost:/my_cool_dir/i_like_this_one/.`, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks @twalberg for the reply! I couple things: I have a `files_to_include.txt` that comes from another process and they are the absolute paths of the `sourcehost` files. Yes it's at a files level :( . Also note the pull strategy (I'm running this from `desthost`).

Answer (score 0):

> is there any option in rsync to re-write the destination path as I want to?

No because the sync part of rsync depends on path, filename, and other meta characteristics as well for not just copying but also deleting.

> a "simple mv" after copying is not good enough

How about a simple mv *before* copying? If that's not feasible, why not make a linked folder structure on the source and then rsync that folder structure to the destination?

> I need it to be smart enough to "peer up" the files

Did you consider making one rsync command for each file? This way you just have to transform source and dest folders once but can re-run the rsync lines multiple times to peer up.

Comment: So, an mv *before* is not possible because it's a production server, that expects the files in a certain place. The linked folder is a good idea but not applicable because I have a list of files (and the folders are filled with other files).  But the last comment is where I'm heading to... I might end up with a big batch file with multiple rsync commands. I'm evaluating the overhead of that. And the required maintenance over time.